# Node on ROS_MASTER -> loosing connection

Tags: ros, master, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently developing a security framework for a robot. The control software as well as the security framework run on the ros master as different nodes with the security node publishing the message to stop the robot to a certain topic (control node subscribes to this topic). My question is how does ROS behave if the master loses the network connection. As both are running on the same machine, would they still be able to communicate?

I assume that they would still be able to do so, but I wasn't able to find anything in the official documentation.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210108/node-on-ros_master--%3E-loosing-connection/) by [canellac](https://answers.ros.org/users/22579/canellac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short, ROS topics are TCP connections directly between nodes, and they will stay connected even if the rosmaster process stops.

For a longer explanation, read the [ROS Technical Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview) and watch my ROSCon presentation from [2013](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/program/):  [slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Networking-for-ROS-Users.pdf) and [video](https://vimeo.com/67806888)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [canellac](https://answers.ros.org/users/22579/canellac/) on 2015-05-28**:
Thanks for the quick answer. I already assumed this behavior, but I wanted to have confirmation as I need it for my bachelor thesis.